# error in django rest api and react in production

Tags: reactjs, django, rest

i have built rest api with django and deploy it to server ,
the problem is **when i call the api from react in my local machine it works**

but when i run `npm run build` and deploy react and django together ,

i got alot of errors in api like `error connection refused` and `403`

note that i have disabled all security and installed django-cors-headers
and i set origin to allow all .

so whats the problem now .

thank you in advanced

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: sorry for being late , i did it now , if you have more questions feel free to tell me about it

Answer (score 0):

***solution ::***
the easiest response in 403 which mean forbidden, that lead me to why i can not access this data?.

so i discovered that the problem was with django rest auth ,

1- if we set django rest auth to `SessionAuthentication` which is the default then we need to obtain the csrf cookie from the browser and include it with the header in `fetch or axios` call

2- if we set django rest auth to `TokenAuthentication` then we need to generate token for every user and then include the token in header with the request

**notes::**
1-you can obtain the csrf token only when you send request to regular view and it response back a template cuz it a django thing , then obtain the csrf and ....

2-when you split the backend and frontend then you must use `TokenAuthentication` because there is no direct response from the server and you can not obtain the csrf token